# Loading CSV file from Google Drive to BigQuery produces zero rows with no errors

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

A vendor provided me with a set of CSV files over Google Drive. When I load it to a new table in BigQuery using the URL to its location in Google Drive it seems to work without any errors, but there are zero rows in the table. The schema loads correctly. When I download the file to my hard drive and upload the same file it works fine - all of the data is there.

Any thoughts on what the problem might be or how to diagnose it?

Comment: Ok, now I see it - "Loading data into BigQuery from Google Drive is not currently supported, but you can query data in Google Drive by using an external table."

Comment: You may want to reply to your question with the answer you found, and describe how the workaround with the external table.

Answer (score 0):

"Loading data into BigQuery from Google Drive is not currently supported, but you can query data in Google Drive by using an external table."